# Swift 3 Google Maps iOS SDK - Add Marker via Touch

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hello Everyone!
I have a Google maps in my iOS app, what i'm trying to do is when i tap or longtouch i add a marker in the map and also save the coordinates in an Array
For example: In Android i have the method `mMap.setOnLongClickListener()` and save those markers in a Latlng Array type

Any help would be useful!
Thanks

Comment: You should use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your `GMSMapView` and implementing the `UIGestureDelegate` protocol to make it work simultaneously with all gestures of `GMSMapView` after that in longPress action you should translate the `CGPoint` of touch and convert it in `CLLocationCoordinate2D`the remain is trivial

**Use this as example**

```
//
//  DashedOverlayViewController.swift
//  GoogleMapsExample
//
//  Created by Reinier Melian on 17/07/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Pruebas. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces



class DashedOverlayViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    var arrayCoordinates : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

    var longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

    @IBAction func longPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        debugPrint("You tapped at YES")
        let newMarker = GMSMarker(position: mapView.projection.coordinate(for: sender.location(in: mapView)))
        self.arrayCoordinates.append(newMarker.position)
        newMarker.map = mapView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(self.longPress))
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension DashedOverlayViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't display the map

Comment: You need to add the map in your storyboard is an IBOutlet @QuickAccount123

Comment: Still empty, i've tried mapView = view as! GMSMapView!

Comment: Also i get this error. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @QuickAccount123 You need add the GMSMapView to your Storyboard ViewController remember that is an example of how make what your need, if you need assistance on how setup a basic GoogleMaps iOS project then let me know

Comment: I think i really need your help, is there any way i contact u fast?

Comment: @QuickAccount123 my gmail account is rmelian2014@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

GMSMapView has a delegate, which has this method:

```
  - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```